# installing antivirus

Tags: install-from-source

Why it is not possible to possible on ubuntu to install antivirus or other software just by downloading exe file instead of using command line? 
Im having all the pains to install free AVG 2014 on ubuntu 12.04
Thanks

Comment: You are trying to do apple juice with only oranges? Why you think that windows antivirus will work in anything else than windows?

Comment: You can use [Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14584), but it likely would not work, and having [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/about/) on your computer would probably increase the likelihood of it being infected with Windows virus.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ubuntu software center to install a program graphically.

For AVG, a antivirus is useless on Ubuntu. In fact, the antivirus will detect Windows virus (which doesn't affect Linux users) in order to avoid your computer to be a vector of virus. Most of the time, on Linux, a virus appears as a file that you can simply delete.

If you still want AVG, follow this link.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus/Avg

You can also install clamTk and clamav from the Software center or

```
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
```